# Quartz Expression that runs every minute only once

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, cron-task, quartz

I have this quartz cron expression: exp = "0 * * ? * *" that runs every minute.
I use this expression as a trigger to call a HTTP POST method every minute.
The problem is that it calls the post method multiple times.
I need an expression that will execute one time in a minute.
Any suggestion how to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This works with Quartz.

Every 1 minute, exactly at the start of a minute - **0 0/1 * * * ?**

Answer (score 3):

How about a simple schedule trigger instead?

```
trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger7", "group1")
    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
        .withIntervalInMinutes(1) )
    .build();
```

Source : [Quartz tutorial-lesson-05 / Build a trigger that will fire now, then repeat every five minutes](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html)

Answer (score 1):

It may happen because request lasts longer than 1 min. You can simply annotate class implemented with Jobs with `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`, which disallow your job execute multiple times in exact time.
You can check [example](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example4) .

Answer (score -1):

use this expression :

"* * * * *"
i.e 5 asteriks
try using that.
use this link for reference :
https://crontab.guru/every-1-minute

Comment: It doesen't work. The  expression is not valid. The expression should be a quartz one.